# bytes.Buffer ReadFrom differ from r.Read?

Tags: go, buffer

I have a situation where I want to take a stream of data from an io Reader and buffer it before sending it as a stream over http post, in the case of connection errors. For this I'm planning to use a bytes.Buffer and copy from the reader to the buffer. A separate goroutine would read from the buffer and pass the reader to a http.Request.

Now, the behavior from bytes.Buffer ReadFrom is not what I'm expecting. I'm simulating a data stream with a pipe:

```
r, w := io.Pipe()
go func() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("foobar %d\n", i)))
        time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    w.Close()
}()
```

When reading from the reader into a byte slice, the Read returns after each write, however, when using ReadFrom, it doesn't stop reading until the writer is closed. This:

```
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    nIn, err = buf.ReadFrom(r)
```

reads all ten lines before returning, while:

```
    buf := make([]byte, 64)
    nIn, err = r.Read(buf)
```

returns after each line. Why is the behavior different?

Comment: Have you consulted [the](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.ReadFrom)?

Comment: Seems I missed the part: **If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.**

Comment: Yup. That's because it closely follows what the `read(2)` OS syscall does. If you need different behaviour, use the `io.ReadFull` helper.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) (`Read`) is defined to be different from [`io.ReadFrom`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReaderFrom).